# Postgresql Insert and Update only replica

Tags: postgresql, replication

Is it possible to create a replica from a database that only inserts and updates replicated and not deletes in PostgreSQL ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, I would say no, but you have some options:

- You can use triggers (with DBLinks if you want to send to another server).
- You can also use Change Data Capture (CDC).

Answer (score 1):

The Postgres [logical replication protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-logicalrep-message-formats.html) allows you to identify the change type, so you *can* write a custom decoder that filters out messages that you want to ignore.

Alternatively, you could use an existing third-party CDC solution that allows filtering by message attributes, such as Debezium.

Comment: built-in pgoutput plugin is enough, no need to write a separate decoder. `create publication ... with (publish = 'insert, update')`